# How to put some delay in calling an activity after clicking button on an another activity

Tags: android-studio

I am developing a simple app. On one of my activity, there is button which calls the another activity. The another activity starts immediately, but I want to put some delay before opening the next activity after clicking the button.
Handler and Timer methods are not working. I have no idea, What to do???

```
public class thumb extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageButton show;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thumb);
    show=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),pop.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
       }

    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Thread.sleep(1000);`? This will stop the execution by 1000 milliseconds.